# What are "Exception sounds"?

Tags: american-english, terminology, orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling, phonics

I'm embarrassed to say I don't understand this 2nd grade homework. Can someone help me understand the concept behind **exception sounds**?

> #### Do the "Sentence Marking" Activity
>
> Have your child read the sentences and scoop into phrases. Highlight or box the exception sounds.
>
> 1. Which man is the best host?
> 2. Wind up the top and let it spin.
> 3. Jess has a bad cold.
> 4. Did you find the lost cat?
> 5. Who sold the most in the class?
> 6. The van hit the post with a jolt.
>
> ---
>
> *Q1 is completed as an example, with brackets under "Which man" and "is the best host", and* ost *in the last word highlighted as an exception sound.*

[image: Image of test paper]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "exception sounds" is not an established collocation in English (if it *did* mean anything it would probably refer to audible noises made by intelligent devices reporting *exception = **error** conditions*). I say this taking particular note of the preceding context, which asks that the child should ***scoop*** the text into phrases (also not something any native speaker would ever say).

Answer (score 2):

The "exceptions" have long vowel sounds as opposed to short ones (in a closed syllable).

How do I know this? Google search reveals this [pdf](http://gke.johnston.k12.nc.us/common/pages/DisplayFile.aspx?itemId=4448132) (don't be ashamed to cheat on your child's homework).

This seems to be a system the publishers thought up to teach kids to read. You really need to have the first page in order to help with the homework, which explains all this:

> The vowel in a closed syllable usually has a short vowel sound like ŭ in the word up. However, there are five exceptions to this rule.
>
> /īld/ as in child
>   /ōld/ as in cold
>   /ōst/ as in post
>   /īnd/ as in kind
>   /ōlt/ as in colt
>
> They are exceptions because the vowel has a long sound (it says its name) rather than a short vowel sound.

Answer (score 0):

It is referring to sounds that violate the normal rules of English pronunciation.

E.g. Lost vs Host.

Lost rhymes with cost whereas host rhymes with most.

The difference is the o in lost is soft, the o in host sounds like the letter o.

Wind is tricky, because if it's the weather, it's soft i, if it's twisting, it's hard i. In this case, hard i.

Comment: In my experience, the usual terminology is "long" and "short" rather than "hard" and "soft": cost has a "short o" sound, "host" has a "long o" sound, "wind" the weather has a "short i" sound, and "wind" the twisting verb has a "long i" sound.

Answer (score 0):

[Exception sounds](http://www.theschoolrun.com/what-are-exception-words) are sounds that don't fit normal rules of English spelling.  As you can imagine, there are tons of them.

In the above, "host" has an exception sound because a lone vowel surrounded by consonants should be short:  that is, "host" should rhyme with "lost."  But it's an exception.  (So are "most" and "post.")

"Wind" should have a short i as in "win."

And so on.

I am not sure how useful this is, but I guess that's another question.

Comment: Would a 2nd grader grasp this? Seems strange

Comment: If that's what they've been taught...

Comment: And I thought inappropriately academic teaching of English to very young children was a British phenomenon.